# Airflow dependencies overwrite each other

Tags: airflow

I am new to airflow (v1.10).
I have two dags each requires the same dependencies but with different versions. how can I make sure that my dependencies will not overwrite each other(for example dag1.py requires helper.py from version v1 and dag2.py requires helper.py from version v2)?

Answer (score 1):

In general I see two possible solutions for your problem:

1. Airflow has a **[PythonVirtualEnvOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html?highlight=pythonvirtualenvoperator#airflow.operators.python_operator.PythonVirtualenvOperator)** which allows a task to run in a virtualenv which gets created and destroyed automatically. You can pass a `python_version` and a list of requirements for the task to build the virtual env.
2. Set up a docker registry and use a **[DockerOperator](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/_modules/airflow/operators/docker_operator.html)** rather than a PythonOperator. This would allow teams to set up their own Docker images with specific requirements. (Suggested by dlamblin)

Comment: Hi kaxil thank you for your answer. option 1 will not work because python will load the two helpers and will overwrite each other. option 2 will work but I ended up creating a unique dependency folder(with unique name) for each DAG.